# Need to redirect "schedule meeting" under Activities subpanel of Leads detail view page to "Full Form" of schedule meeting

Tags: sugarcrm

I have to redirect "schedule meeting" under Activities subpanel of Leads list view page to "Full Form" of schedule meeting

I have looked at modules/Leads/metadata/subpaneldefs.php and removed top_buttons array key, but it is removing the buttons. How to make the schedule meeting button redirect to full form of meeting instead of quick meeting?

Also, I have to make id(parent_name) field of "related to" label required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override the **SugarWidgetSubPanelTopScheduleMeetingButton** widget class file located at ***include/generic/SugarWidgets/*** because for Activites subpanel Schedule Meeting button calls **SubPanelTopScheduleCallButton** widget class.

And for making parent_name required.

- Go to Admin Panel
- then Studio
- Select Your Module
- Select Fields
- Edit parent_name field
- Enable Required checkbox
- Click on Save button

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I didn't understand the answer on redirecting the quick meeting to full form. Can you please elaborate the answer?

Comment: Hi Uday, You only need to override the **&_get_form** function in **SugarWidgetSubPanelTopScheduleMeetingButton.php** file. Compare same function between this file and **SugarWidgetSubPanelTopButton.php** and make the changes in your file.

Comment: HI Shahid, Thanks for your comment. But the main file is in include/generic/SugarWidgets/SugarWidgetSubPanelTopScheduleMeetingButton.php.
How to override this file from my custom meetings module? where should I keep my local file? 

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Shahid, I am able to achieve the functionality. Thanks buddy.